# Java: matching repeating character at beginning of new line and replacing with same number of alternatives

Tags: java, regex, whitespace

I have a plain text file with a number of lines (new line character is `\n`) Some of these lines start with a varying number of sequential repeating whitespace characters `\\s`. I want to replace each `\\s` with `&nbsp;`. Example file:

```
This is a line with no white space at the beginning
  This is a line with 2 whitespace characters at the beginning
    This is a line with 4 whitespace at the beginning
```

transforms to:

```
This is a line with no white space at the beginning
&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a line with two whitespace characters at the beginning
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;This is a line with 4 whitespace at the beginning
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)(?:^|\\G) ", "&nbsp;");
```

`^` in MULTILINE mode matches the beginning of a line.
`\G` matches the spot where the previous match ended (or the beginning of the input if there is no previous match).

If you're processing one line at a time, you can shorten the regex to `"\\G "`.

Comment: I wouldn't have got that in a million years, thanks. +1 for the \\G

Answer (score 1):

//try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));
String line;
StringBuffer buffer;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  buffer = new StringBuffer();
  int index = line.indexOf(line.trim());
  for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    buffer.append("&nbsp;");
  }

  buffer.append(line.subString(index) + "\n"); 
  System.out.println(buffer.toString()); 
} 
reader.close();
```

//some more cleanup code here

Comment: You will lose trailing spaces in the original input

Answer (score 1):

```
String line;
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
int i;
for (i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
{
    if (line.charAt(i) == ' ')
        buf.append("&nbsp;");
    else
        break;
}
if (i < line.length()) buf.append(line.substr(i));
line = buf.toString();
```

Comment: Interesting that both answers so far don't use a regex, which was my original approach. Thanks.

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark Alan Moore's regex-based solution against my simple approach.